# Can I create a self-closing element with createElement?

Tags: javascript, html, prepend, createelement

I'm trying to append a line of HTML before all the children of the `body`.

Right now I have this:

```
// Prepend vsr-toggle
var vsrToggle = document.createElement("div");
vsrToggle.innerHTML = "<input type='checkbox' name='sr-toggle' id='srToggle'><label for='srToggle' role='switch'>Screen reader</label>"
document.body.insertBefore(vsrToggle, pageContent);
```

It's working fine because the HTML is being added to the created `div`. However, I need to prepend this element without wrapping it in a div.

Is there a way to prepend the HTML without first creating an element? If not, can I create the `input` as a self-closing element and append the `label` to it?

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Cheers!

Comment: Use `insertBefore()` to insert the `<input>`, then call it again to insert the `<label>`. Self-closing has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php dom create element but self-closing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56260630/php-dom-create-element-but-self-closing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use document.createDocumentFragment() to create a node, that isn't automatically added to the document. You can then add elements to this fragment and finally add it to the document.

This is a good link: [Document fragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment)

**How to use**:

```
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
fragment.innerHTML = '<input />';
document.body.appendChild(fragment);
```

Comment: Didn't know about this extremely useful feature, thanks for sharing!

Comment: That's where I landed... See my answer below. Isn't `createRange` needed for multiple elements? Otherwise, you'd have to keep calling `createDocumentFragment`.

Comment: You add elements to the fragment, as needed, creating an element-tree, then finally adding the fragment to the document.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using `createRange` and `createContextualFragment` to turn the string into a node that I could prepend using `insertBefore`.:

```
// Prepend vsr-toggle
var vsrToggle = document.createRange().createContextualFragment("<input 
type='checkbox' name='sr-toggle' id='srToggle'><label for='srToggle' 
role='switch'>Screen reader</label>");
document.body.insertBefore(vsrToggle, pageContent);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: As Poul Bak showed, there is a very useful feature in the DOM API for that. Creating elements separately (instead of having them parsed as a string) allows more control over the elements added (for example you can outright attach an event listener without queryiing it from the DOM later), but for a larger amounts of elements it quickly becomes *very* verbose.

Create each element separately, and insert it before the body content using

```
document.body.insertBefore(newNode, document.body.firstChild);
```

```js
const vsrToggle = document.createElement("input");
vsrToggle.name="sr-toggle";
vsrToggle.id="srToggle";
vsrToggle.type="checkbox";

const vsrToggleLabel = document.createElement("label");
vsrToggleLabel.setAttribute("for", vsrToggle.id);
vsrToggleLabel.setAttribute("role", "switch");
vsrToggleLabel.textContent = "Screen reader";

document.body.insertBefore(vsrToggle, document.body.firstChild);
document.body.insertBefore(vsrToggleLabel, document.body.firstChild);
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Body headline</h1>
  <p>Some random content</p>
</body>
```